# Gear minimum amount of teeth

Tags: gears, manufacturing-engineering, lasers

So I know from college (and a bit of googling, not gonna lie) that the minimum amount of teeth on a gear is 17 due to undercut forming in traditional cutting manufacturing.

Does this rule still hold valid if the gear is laser cut and there is no (at least I see none) undercut on the gear?

I'm asking because fewer teeth mean less travel thus a cheaper cut, when cutting a lot of gears, and I can achieve my gear ratios with 11 or even 9 tooth gears.

I'm attaching a CAD image of an 11 tooth gear with (correct me if I'm wrong) no undercut:

[image]

Comment: Repaired a gear drive the other day with 7 teeth. So not sure about your 17... However, it was a male/female thing.

Comment: Starter motor drives have 9 teeth.. engage with a flywheel ring gear.

Comment: I saw a pinion once with 7 teeth. For use in model helicopters.

Comment: Differentials in rear wheel drive cars "always" have fewer than 17 teeth on the pinion gear. '"Always"  in those I have seen.